# Cannot Build Confluent Common repo

Tags: maven, confluent-platform, confluent-schema-registry

I'm trying to build Confluent schema registry which requires `common` and `rest-utils` to be built. But I'm unable to build `common` from source and getting the following Maven error:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-install-plugin:2.5.2:install-file (custom-install) on project common-parent: The specified file '/Users/abc/dev/apache/common-7.0.1/installed_pom.xml' not exists -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-install-plugin:2.5.2:install-file (custom-install) on project common-parent: The specified file '/Users/abc/dev/apache/common-7.0.1/installed_pom.xml' not exists
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:215)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:156)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:148)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:305)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:192)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:105)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:972)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:293)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:196)
...
```

Where can I find the `installed_pom.xml` file?

Comment: Do you need to build the master branches? If you are trying to install Schema Registry, just run it in Docker or download Confluent Platform and just run it by itself

Comment: This issue still persists not only for master branch but for all branches higher than 6.0.9-post (latest 6.0 version as of time of this writing). Once you try to build 6.1.0-post and higher the installed_pom.xml starts suddenly to be needed.

Comment: In fact, 6.1.0-post fails with "Could not find any ccs-kafka artifacts", but 6.1.1-post already fails with "The specified file '.../confluent/common/installed_pom.xml' not exists"

Comment: @SergeyShcherbakov The order of execution is `github.com/confluentinc/kafka` (install with Gradle, checkout correct tag first), then `confluentinc/common`, `rest-utils`, then `schema-registry` (all same tag/branch, all with Maven)